# Terraform switch?

Tags: terraform

I have a question around Terraform.

I have set up a few files, and I am able to create VM-s well with this on vSphere. But in the current company:

- we have two clusters where VM-s can be deployed
- we also have two AD domains where VM-s can be joined

I have written a few pieces of code where, and it works well, but the problem is that each time that I want to deploy VM-s from this code to lets say clusterA, where the network is 1.2.3.4/24, gateway is 1.2.3.1, and so on, then I put these to the code as default. Then, when I to deploy to clusterB, I need to update all these variables, eg. to network being 1.2.4.4/24, gateway to 1.2.4.1 and so on.
Can a switch logic be introduced somehow, so for example:

- if a variable (read this from console, something similar to PS-s Read-Host) is 'foo', use this set or variables. If that variable is 'bar', use a different set of variables. If the variable the user entered is neither 'foo' or 'bar', then throw an error?

I know this is not the best approach, and since I am more well-versed in PowerShell, if Terraform does not support switch statements (or so I red), I will eventually do a workaround (writing a PS script which takes a template file, takes a switch, and depending on the user's choice replaces variables in the template file before running terraform plan / apply), but I would prefer to keep everything in Terraform...

My starter code is here (sorry for the lot of comments, it is meant to be given to more junior / not familiar with TF team members, so needs to be wordy...): https://code.prkr.li/4W4RsYTEm3

To give an example:

```
    variable "vm_to_clone" {
  description = "Enter the name of the vM that we will clone:"
  # ! THIS IS THE VM THAT YOU ARE CLONING 
  # * changeme ->
  # default = "bnw_2019_gui" # * uncomment this line for deploying in BN
  default = "alw_2019_gui" # * uncomment this line for deploying in AL
}
```

- currently this would use the template I have set up in "ALW" cluster. To use the template of "BNW" cluster, I would need to comment the 'bnw_2019_gui' line  out and comment the 'alw_2019_gui' line. (Or of course give an overriding value with the terraform plan / apply). But I would prefer switching based on the chosen cluster.

Any tips please?

Thanks

Answer (score 24):

The `switch` in itself is not supported by TF, but you could use regular [map](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/types.html#map) for what `switch` would be used (if I understand your use-case correctly).

So instead of heaving all your variables separate, you could bundle them into one `map` with keys `foo` and `bar`. Which key to use, you would provide from the console.

Rough example:

```
variable "cluster" {
}


variable "setup" {

  default = { 
     "foo" = {
        "vm_to_clone" = "bnw_2019_gui"
        "vm_folder" = "BN-ALL-SIMPLIVITY-VMS"
        # and the rest
      },
     "bar" = {
        "vm_to_clone" = "alw_2019_gui"
        "vm_folder" = "AL-ALL-SIMPLIVITY-VMS"
        # and the rest
      },
  }
}
```

Then, depending on your `cluster` (either `foo` or `bar`), you would use different values of the veriables in the rest of your code:

```
data "vsphere_virtual_machine" "template_vm" {
  name          = var.setup[var.cluster].vm_to_clone
  datacenter_id = data.vsphere_datacenter.target_datacenter.id
}

# and similarly for the rest.
```

Comment: Yay! This seems like exactly the thing that I have looking for! Kudos for this!  (Shame on me not reading on it enough on the Hashicorp docs...)

Comment: @krapulax Acceptance of the answer would be appreciated if this is "exactly the thing that I have looking for".

Answer (score 2):

Original Switch-case is not supported, but we can use the equal **Switch-Case** based on the ternary chain:

```
locals {
  scope = (                                                    # switch

    local.cluster_type == module.global_vars.dev_cluster ?     # case 1
    module.global_vars.dev_scope :                             # then

    local.cluster_type == module.global_vars.demo_cluster ?    # case 2
    module.global_vars.demo_scope :                            # then

    local.cluster_type == module.global_vars.staging_cluster ? # case 3
    module.global_vars.staging_scope :                         # then

    local.cluster_type == module.global_vars.prod_scope ?      # case 4
    module.global_vars.prod_scope :                            # then

    module.global_vars.default_scope                           # default

  )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I think you should look at creating a module which you can abstract alot of this behind so you don't have a crazy long list of things to change which depend on other values.

You can also use ternary operator for differing values dependent on a `var`

```
var.location == "BN"  ? "10.171.16." : "10.171.17."
```

Then your user only has to change the location. I wouldn't rely on someone successfully changing lots of variables and getting it right.

The other thing we do is use a `config.yml` file which has the variables required then at deploy time the yaml file values are tokenised into the tfvars file so the user doesn't have to change any tf files at all. Just a list of values for their environment

Comment: Thanks. I think that leads to somewhere where I want to get, but the mapping-one (from Marcin) seems more sensible for me...unless I am wrong, with that, if the location is "BN" then it puts the 10.171.16 network, else the 10.171.17, which is fine as long as there is only two network/set of values, but if/else would need if/elseif/else at some point, had we have 3x sets...I go with the mapping for now, but thanks for pointing this out too!

Answer (score 1):

This type of pattern can be used. All your logic is in one place, in the `att_values_map` local.

```
locals {   
    att_values_map = {
        "a" = "value_a",
        "b" = "value_b",
        "c" = "value_c",
        "default" = "value_default"   
    }
}

resource ... ... {
    att = lookup(local.att_values_map, var.case, local.att_values_map["default"])
}
```

The above example is equivalent to this pseudo code:

```
att = switch (var.case) 
     case "a" then "value_a"
     case "b" then "value_b"
     case "c" then "value_c"
     default then "value_default"
```